# Entity Framework .Include() Navigation of another Navigation property

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an entity *Test*. It contains a Navaigation Property *Question* and *Question* contains a Navigation Property *QuestionLocale*.

```
var test = context.Tests
       .Include("Question")
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

works as expected. But how is it possible to include the *QuestionLocale*?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use:

```
var test = context.Tests
                  .Include("Question.QuestionLocale")
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: With EntityFramework 4.1 and later, I believe, there is an extension in System.Data.Entity on IDbSet where you can write .Include(x => x.Question.QuestionLocale).

Comment: @AndreasLarsen, any specifics on `.Include(x => x.Question.QuestionLocale)`? I can't figure out exactly how to do that...

Comment: @edobry add a using statement: `System.Data.Entity` then when you type `.Include()` there will be overloads for the lambda.

Comment: This answer has just saved me from hours of headache. Thanks a lot !

Comment: fantastic. I wasted several hours to find this solution.

Answer (score 6):

Now there is `ThenInclude` see [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager), that solved it for me

```cs
var test = context.Tests.Include(x => x.Question).ThenInclude(q => q.QuestionLocale).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: But only in EF-core, not in EF6 (classic).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in a strongly typed way too

```
var test = context.Tests
                .Include(x => x.Question.Select(child => child.QuestionLocale))
                .FirstOrDefault()
```