# How does one deal with schema changes and using the Include method in the Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, linq-to-entities, database-schema

Example code taken from [another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614809/entity-framework-include-load)

```
var test = context.Tests
                  .Include("Question.QuestionLocale")
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

If your DB schema needed to change for some reason, how could a developer possibly deal with hard-coded values used in a method that takes a string parameter (Include method used as an example), and know there's a problem?

I was under the impression that one of the big selling points of Linq-to-Entities was its strongly-typed nature; once a change in the schema is made, and the corresponding Entity Data Model is updated, you would know right away there is a problem, because your code can't compile anymore. Doesn't this break strong typing? Are there alternatives to using this construct (I'm new to EF - so I have lots of questions, some of which are elementary)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one workaround: [How to implement an Eager Loading strategy](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/07/25/tip-28-how-to-implement-include-strategies.aspx)