# EF 4.0 What should the path parameter supplied to Include() be?

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-objects

When using [`Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in my LINQ against my model should the path parameter I supply be the name of the related objects or the name of the Navigation Property?

I ask because the same table has more than one relationship to the same other table. I note in the designer the navigation properties of related table are in the form:

```
RelatedTable
RelatedTable1
...
RelatedTablen
```

Lazy loading is off so I need to explicitly load related objects. I am only want the objects related through the Navigation Property: "RelatedTable1" I have tried supplying the Navigation Property name (i.e. "RelatedTable1") to Include, i.e.:

```
from row in Table.Include("RelatedTable1")
select row
```

and it works! Which suggests the path parameter should be the name of the Navigation Property. However I have also tried just the related Entity's name, i.e.:

```
from row in Table.Include("RelatedTable")
select row
```

and it works too! I am just asking to understand what is going on..

(LazyLoading is off and if I do not use Include() related is not fetched).

Comment: The name of the navigation property. Of course it works. You've got both `RelatedTable` and `RelatedTable1` as navigation properties. But the joined fields are different.

Comment: thanks - you are right i shouldn't have been surprised is should have concluded it must be the navigation property being used. still i think this is something the documentation should state!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the name of the Navigation properties, or you can chain them [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614809/entity-framework-include-navigation-of-another-navigation-property):

```
db.Tables.Include("RelatedTable.RelatedTable2");
```

Or if you prefer strongly typing, you could  [include as a lambda](http://romiller.com/2010/07/14/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-include-with-lambda/):

```
db.Tables.Include(x => x.RelatedTable);
```